# Is std::push_heap working for O(n) complexity instead of O(logN) in this case?

Tags: c++, time-complexity, std, binary-heap

I replaced one random element of heap and then called push_heap on this container. What complexity does it have in this case: O(n) or O(logN)?

```
/* heap elements are stored on a random-access container */
std::vector<int> Q = { 3, 4, 2, 1 };

/* heapify Q (linear run-time complexity) */
std::make_heap(Q.begin(), Q.end());

std::cout << std::is_heap(Q.begin(), Q.end()) << std::endl;
std::cout << Q[3] << std::endl;
Q[3] = 5;
std::push_heap(Q.begin(), Q.end());
std::cout << std::is_heap(Q.begin(), Q.end()) << std::endl;
```

Comment: The standard requires _"...At most log(N) comparisons..."_ : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/push_heap

Comment: What is `n` and what is `N`?

Comment: @ThomasSablik it's the same, misprint :) Number of max elements in heap

Comment: The complexity does not change. If you change `Q.back()` the heap is valid after `std::push_heap(Q.begin(), Q.end());`. If you change an element other than `Q.back()` the behavior is not defined. The heap could get invalid. The complexity is O(log N). If you have to change a random element call `make_heap` instead of `push_heap` with complexity O(N).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking the wrong question. Instead of asking for time complexity you should ask whether what you are doing is well defined behavior.

Answer:
`push_heap` has the precondition that the range you pass it is a valid heap. More precisely, if you give it the range `[first, last[`, only `[first, last-1[` is required to be a heap and the element at `last-1` will be inserted. So if this precondition is not met, the behavior is undefined (and this is the case with `push_heap` as with any other STL algorithms as far as I know). But if the precondition is met, you are guaranteed to get O(log N) here.

In your example the heap is still valid, because you are changing the last element (which is not required to be part of the heap), so the complexity stays O(log N). If it were no heap anymore, in theory, anything could happen: Crash, O(n), O(2^n), nose dragons.

In practice, however, the complexity will stay at O(log N) because the new entry will still sift through at max O(log N) heap layers, even if one of them is incorrect and sifting stops incorrectly (actually, if the heap is incorrect in the first place, there cannot be "correct" sifting).

Comment: It is possible to rearrange heap faster than O(n) after modifying the random element?

Comment: @Robotex Yes, it is. You would "just" have to swap the changed element upwards or downwards in the heap until it doesn't violate the heap condition anymore (parent must be >= children). This will take at most O(log N) swaps, limited by the depth of the heap. But you'd have to do this manually, I'm not aware of a STL algorithm doing this

Comment: @Robotex see the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20397674/replacing-element-in-min-heap
It's for a min-heap and written in Java, but you should be able to adapt it easily

Answer (score 3):

The time complexity of [`std::push_heap`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/push_heap/) is logarithmic, i.e. O(logN):

> Up to **logarithmic** in the *distance between first and last*: Compares elements and potentially swaps (or moves) them until rearranged as a longer heap.

where `N = std::distance(first, last)`.

Note: In case you call this method on an **invalid heap**,  as @interjay commented, "the *behavior* is **undefined** and you can't know its **complexity** or effects", since that method won't re-organize the heap into a valid one. The [ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/push_heap/) states:

> **Given a heap** in the range [first,last-1), this function extends the range considered a heap to [first,last) by placing the value in (last-1) into its corresponding location within it.

So, if I was actually doing this, then I wouldn't worry about the time complexity, but for the unpredicted behavior.

---

In order, to demonstrate that behavior try changing the 2nd element (any but the last, as @ThomasSablik commented - because if you change `Q.back()` the heap is valid after `std::push_heap(Q.begin(), Q.end());`), and you'll notice that the heap remains invalid after `std::push_heap`'s call - you need to call the linear (in complexity) method [`std::make_heap`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/make_heap/) to re-organize your now invalidated heap.

Comment: Yes, but in case if container is a valid heap. Changing of one element making heap invalid, so, theoretically, complexity should be O(n). Am I right?

Comment: @Robotex you are changing the last element. After `std::push_heap` the heap is valid. If you would change a random element other than the last the heap could be invalid after `push_heap`. The complexity is the same.

Comment: Regarding the note at the end: If you call this on an invalid heap, the behavior is undefined and you can't know its complexity or effects. But in this case the heap is valid.

Comment: @interjay & Thomas you are right, I improved the answer with your comments, hope that's fine. :)

Comment: @Robotex no, see my improved answer please. :) Nice question BTW, +1.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I'm changing not last element, I'm changing random.

Comment: @Robotex In your code snipped you are changing the element with index 3 of your vector with size 4. That's the last element and the behavior is defined. If you would change element with index 2 in the same vector the behavior is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

The complexity `push_heap` does not change but it's only well defined if you change the last element.

If you change `Q.back()` the heap is valid after `std::push_heap(Q.begin(), Q.end());`. If you change an element other than `Q.back()` the behavior is not defined. The heap could get invalid. The complexity is O(log N) in any case.

If you have to change a random element call `make_heap` instead of `push_heap` with complexity O(N) or use a custom function like:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using Container = std::vector<int>;

void push_heap(Container &Q, Container::size_type index, Container::value_type value) {
    Q[index] = value;
    for (Container::size_type i{index + 1}; i > 1; i /= 2) {
        if (Q[i - 1] <= Q[i/2 - 1]) break;
        std::swap(Q[i - 1], Q[i/2 - 1]);
    }
}

int main() {
    Container Q = { 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 };

    std::make_heap(Q.begin(), Q.end());

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_heap(Q.begin(), Q.end()) << '\n';
    for (const auto &el : Q) {
        std::cout << el << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    push_heap(Q, 4, 20);
    // Q[4] = 20;
    // std::push_heap(Q.begin(), Q.end());
    std::cout << std::is_heap(Q.begin(), Q.end()) << '\n';
    for (const auto &el : Q) {
        std::cout << el << ' ';
    }
}
```

This function sets an element of the heap and preserves the heap property in O(log N).

Output:

```
true
32 16 4 8 2 1 
true
32 20 4 8 16 1
```

In the example element `Q[4]` is set to 20. The behavior of `push_heap` is not defined for this case. The usual result is an invalid heap. As you can see the custom `push_heap` function reorganizes the heap in log(N) iterations and returns a valid heap.

Comment: > If you have to change a random element call make_heap

too slow

Is it possible to reorganise heap faster that O(n) if random element was changed?

Comment: @Robotex My code has a complexity of O(log N) and you can set a random element